# Getting the strings from line strings, from an ArrayList in java)

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList:

```
private static ArrayList<String> lista;

static void fileReading() {

inp = new LineNumberReader(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFileNev), "ISO8859-1")));

            String sor;
            while ((sor = inp.readLine()) != null) {

               lista.add(sor);
               lista.add(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

I need the strings from this, not the whole line (like "pakcage" and "asd;").
I tried these but none of these works:

```
String[] temp=null;
for(String s : lista) {
   temp = s.split("\\W+"); 
} 
System.out.println(temp);
```

I get: [Ljava.lang.String;@6ef53890
If I write println Within the for I get the same, just more of this.

If I use this:

```
   String str ="" ;
    for(int i=0; i<lista.size(); i++){
     str+=lista.get(i)+" ";

  String[] temp = new String[str.length()];
  for(int i=0; i < str.length(); i++) {
       temp[i]=str.valueOf(i);
       System.out.println(temp[i]);         
  }
```

I get only numbers, and can't figure out how to get the strings from str.
I need to know the strings indexes, and replace them later.

Answer (score 0):

In this example

```
String[] temp=null;
for(String s : lista) {
    temp = s.split("\\W+"); 
} 
System.out.println(temp);
```

Trying to print an object will result in invoking its `toString()` method. In fact you are not printing any `String` value, but an array of `Strings`, which is an object.

In your second snippet `str.valueOf(i);` is returning a "string representation of the *int* argument."

What you probably want to do is

1. Split your elements into some table, like you did here `temp = s.split("\\W+");`
2. And then iterate through the array using `foreach`:

Which would look like

```
for (String s : yourStringArray) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Hope this helps... after almost a year ;)